# How to get sources from obfuscated JAR

Tags: java, android, jar, deobfuscation

Decided to decompile .apk file

`dex2jar` helped me to get a JAR file

and I can open sources with `JD GUI`

**But all the code is obfuscated**

Is there any way (maybe some tool) to decrypt sources and get real code ??

Comment: You can't de-obfuscate code. Luckily. So we are protected against **thieves**.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is **about stealing someone else's code**

Comment: To Der Gole : nope, **it is about theoretical possibility to do that** - not about stealing someone else's code.

Comment: I am just a newbie - developer, not a thief !!

Comment: But you want to steal someone else's code.

Comment: I wanted to look at someone else's code. But maybe that's a crime too.

Comment: Probably this someone **doesn't want you to**. Thet's why they obfuscated their code against people like you. So, you're trying to **force a private property**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obfuscation is used for

- decreasing the size of compiled code
- performance improvements
- preventing from unauthorized persons to take a look on the source code

The last usage is like usage of door lock, so your question can be re-phrased as "how to enter locked door if I do not have keys?" :)

So, if we forget the justice side and concentrate on technical aspects we can say that obfesactor actually just changes  names of variables, classes, methods to something short and meaningless. If you are able to see this code and can understand meaning of specific variable, change its name using regular IDE re-factoring feature. Then move to other variable/method. Etc, etc. I do not believe that there can be more automatic tool, because only human can understand and decide what is the role of specific variable or method and rename it.

I really hope that you are not going against the law and really do not want to be the helper of criminal. Again, I concentrated on technical issues only.